# How to remove double quotes from json object

Tags: javascript

My JSON object looks like below

```
"{'EN':{'APP_TITLE':'TESTHEADING'}}"
```

Can some help me on removing the double quotes at first position and last position I tried with regex but not able to remove it.

Comment: If you remove those you won't have valid JSON anymore, unless you also replace all the single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Paulpro it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `.substring()` like below:

```js
let input = "\"{'EN':{'APP_TITLE':'TESTHEADING'}}\"";
let output = input.substring(1, input.length - 1);

console.log(`Input: ${input} \nOutput: ${output}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

- To remove the double quotes at the beginning and end, you can use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). It take a start index (here `1` skipping the first character) and an end (here `str.length - 1` skipping the last)
- To have a valid *JSON string* you also need to replace the *single quotes* with *double quotes*. To do that you can use a regex with the function [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The `g` option replace all occurences of your target character `' => "`
- To load this as an object (for further processing) in JavaScript, use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). This will convert your JSON string into an actual object.

Combining the 3 steps will give you something like this

```js
const str = "\"{'EN':{'APP_TITLE':'TESTHEADING'}}\"";
const withoutQuotes = str
  .substring(1, str.length - 1)
  .replace(/'/g, '"');
const actualJSON = JSON.parse(withoutQuotes);

console.log(actualJSON);
```